# JGit commit problem on Android

Tags: android, jgit

I am trying to use the JGit library to synch documents on my android phone to a server.

It almost works... but I can not get the commit to work. Whenever I try a commit I get an exception "data error". I tracked down the problem to the following statements in org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO:

```
public static void readFully(final InputStream fd, final byte[] dst,
        int off, int len) throws IOException {
    while (len > 0) {
        final int r = fd.read(dst, off, len);
        if (r <= 0)
            throw new EOFException(JGitText.get().shortReadOfBlock);
        off += r;
        len -= r;
    }
}
```

The line fd.read(dst, off, len) will throw the execption. I think the fd parameter is an InflaterInputStream so this code tries to read from a compressed archive.

A am trying to run this on an HTC Desire Z with Android 2.2.

I am using org.eclipse.jgit-0.12.1.jar and com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.31.jar to access the jgit functionality.

I have done some test examples to try to understand the problem

The following code runs without problems on my Windows XP machine:

```
public class Test {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Create a new directory
        File dirF = new File("C:\\Test\\TestDir");
        dirF.mkdir();
        log(">>> Created directory.\n");

        // Initialize git repository
        InitCommand init = Git.init();
        File initFile = new File("C:\\Test\\TestDir");
        init.setDirectory(initFile);
        init.call();
        log(">>> Git Init done.\n");

        // Create a file
        File newfile = new File("C:\\Test\\TestDir\\myfile.txt");
        newfile.createNewFile();
        PrintStream os = new PrintStream(newfile);
        os.println("Some text");
        os.close();
        log(">>> File created.\n");

        // Add to git
        FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        File f = new File("C:\\Test\\TestDir\\.git");
        Repository db = builder.setGitDir(f)
        .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
        .build();
        Git git = new Git(db);
        AddCommand add = git.add();
        add.addFilepattern(".").call();
        log(">>> Git Add done.\n");

        // Commit the change
        CommitCommand commit = git.commit();
        commit.setAll(true);
        commit.setMessage("A JGit message");
        commit.call();
        log(">>> Git Commit done.\n");

        // Check the log
        for (RevCommit c : git.log().call()) {
            log(c.getId() + "/" + c.getAuthorIdent().getName() + "/"
                    + c.getShortMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private static void log(String s) {
    System.out.print(s);
}

}
```

The following code will throw an exception on my android phone:

```
public class JGitSimpleAndroidActivity extends Activity {
StringBuilder sb;
TextView tv;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    tv = new TextView(this);
    try {
        // Create a new directory
        File sdCard;
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        } else {
            log(">>> SD card is not available.");
            return;
        }
        File dirF = new File(sdCard,"TestDir");
        dirF.mkdir();
        log(">>> Created directory.\n");

        // Initialize git repository
        InitCommand init = Git.init();
        init.setDirectory(dirF);
        init.call();
        log(">>> Git Init done.\n");

        // Create a file
        File newfile = new File(dirF,"myfile.txt");
        newfile.createNewFile();
        PrintStream os = new PrintStream(newfile);
        os.println("Some text");
        os.close();
        log(">>> File created.\n");

        // Add to git
        FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        File f = new File(dirF,".git");
        Repository db = builder.setGitDir(f)
        .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
        .build();
        Git git = new Git(db);
        AddCommand add = git.add();
        add.addFilepattern(".").call();
        log(">>> Git Add done.\n");

        // Commit the change
        CommitCommand commit = git.commit();
        commit.setAll(true);
        commit.setMessage("A JGit message");
        commit.call(); // >>>>>>>> EXCEPTION THROWN HERE <<<<<<<
        log(">>> Git Commit done.\n");

        // Check the log
        for (RevCommit c : git.log().call()) {
            log(c.getId() + "/" + c.getAuthorIdent().getName() + "/"
                    + c.getShortMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log(e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void log(String s) {
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append('\n');
    tv.setText(sb);
    setContentView(tv);
}
}
```

Any ideas of what I can do to make this work?

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 0):

Cool!

Try this patch: (it's probably white-space damaged, so applying it as-is may not work)

```
   diff --git a/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/IO.java b/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/IO.java index 4b9c572..4e38747 100644
    --- a/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/IO.java
    +++ b/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/IO.java @@ -214,7 +214,7 @@ public static void readFully(final InputStream fd, final byte[] dst,
                            int off, int len) throws IOException {
                    while (len > 0) {
                            final int r = fd.read(dst, off, len);
    -                       if (r <= 0)
    +                       if (r < 0)
                                    throw new EOFException(JGitText.get().shortReadOfBlock);
                            off += r;
                            len -= r; 
@@ -242,7 +242,7 @@ public static void skipFully(final InputStream fd, long toSkip)
                            throws IOException {
                    while (toSkip > 0) {
                            final long r = fd.skip(toSkip);
    -                       if (r <= 0)
    +                       if (r < 0)
                                    throw new EOFException(JGitText.get().shortSkipOfBlock);                          
                            toSkip -= r;
                }
```

Comment: Tried it, but I'm afraid it doesn't help. It is the call to fd.read(dst, off, len) that throws the exception, not the if (r <= 0) test afterwards.

Comment: Any other ideas would be appreciated. Regards,

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug at bugs.eclipse.org. Include a complete stack trace.

Comment: I reported a bug on bugs.eclipse.org a couple of days ago. Not much action though. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=347485

Comment: But I actually have it working anyway using a patch of one method in JGit:

Comment: See comments in the bug report above in case you are interested in the details.
'